# Spatial autocorrelation analysis withe several observations per location in R

Tags: r, spatial, autocorrelation

I have data collected from several sampling sites across a landscape.
Each individual sample has a unique dependent variable (y) and explanatory variables shared with 9 other samples:

```
DependentVar<-rnorm(60,mean = 9.5,sd=.5)
Temperature<-rep(c(23.5,18,26.1,24.7,20.8,20),each=10)
SpatData<-data.frame(x = rep(runif(6,0,100),each=10), y = rep(runif(6,0,100),each=10))
SpatData$Temperature<-Temperature
SpatData$DependentVar<-DependentVar
```

I have constructed a linear model to test the influence of temp. on the dependent variable:

```
SpatLM<-lm(DependentVar~Temperature,data = SpatData)
```

Then I have tried to test for autocorrelation of the residuals like so:

```
library(DHARMa)
sims<-simulateResiduals(SpatLM)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(sims, x=SpatData$x,y=SpatData$y)
```

The message I got was:

> Error in testSpatialAutocorrelation(sims, x = SpatData$x, y = SpatData$y) : 
>     testing for spatial autocorrelation requires unique x,y values - if you have several observations per location, either use the recalculateResiduals function to aggregate residuals per location, or extract the residuals from the fitted object, and plot / test each of them independently for spatially repeated subgroups (a typical scenario would repeated spatial observation, in which case one could plot / test each time step separately for temporal autocorrelation). Note that the latter must be done by hand, outside testSpatialAutocorrelation.

Using `recalculateResiduals()` doesn't seem to work, with or without grouping:
`simsrecalc<-recalculateResiduals(sims,group = SpatData$Temperature)`

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given in the error message. Look at your simulated data for `SpatData$x`:

```
SpatData$x
#>  [1] 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469 14.65469
#> [11] 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340 55.59340
#> [21] 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651 88.07651
#> [31] 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331 58.31331
#> [41] 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448 30.44448
#> [51] 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158 53.43158
```

Every value repeats 10 times because of the way you have generated the random data. The same is true of the y values. You therefore only have 6 unique (x, y) co-ordinates in your data, and you are asking for a spatial autocorrelation when some of the samples are co-located. This is a bit like trying to analyse a time series of stock values when you have ten different values for the stock price at each point in time. It doesn't really make any sense.

If you create your test data frame using `runif(60, 0, 100)` for x and do the same for y, the problem disappears, because now you have 60 unique (x, y) co-ordinates.

Your description of your real data isn't really clear enough to know if this is a real problem or not. Assuming you do have several samples from each location, you need to decide what to do with them. If they are all different variables, then you just put them in different columns of your data frame. If they are multiple measurements of the same variable (as in your example), you need to decide whether you want to average them or (if they were taken at different times) whether you want to run a spatial autocorrelation at each time point.

Here is an example of taking the mean temperature at each point and using that for the spatial autocorrelation:

```r
library(DHARMa)
library(dplyr)

SpatData <- data.frame(x = rep(runif(6, 0, 100), each = 10), 
                       y = rep(runif(6, 0, 100), each = 10),
                       Temperature = rep(c(23.5, 18, 26.1, 24.7, 20.8, 20), each = 10),
                       DependentVar = rnorm(60, mean = 9.5, sd = 0.5))

MeanData <- SpatData %>% 
  group_by(x, y)     %>% 
  summarize(Temperature = mean(Temperature), DependentVar = mean(DependentVar)) 

SpatLM <- lm(DependentVar ~ Temperature, data = MeanData)
sims   <- simulateResiduals(SpatLM)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(sims, x = MeanData$x, y = MeanData$y)
```

[image]

```
#> 
#>  DHARMa Moran's I test for spatial autocorrelation
#> 
#> data:  sims
#> observed = -0.45465, expected = -0.20000, sd = 0.19274, p-value =
#> 0.1864
#> alternative hypothesis: Spatial autocorrelation
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The data is of plant attributes. I have sampled plants in several locations, several plants per sampling site. Hence the similar temp. and coordinates. I need to test whether there is an impact of distance between sampling sites on the plants' attributes. I'm not sure whether summing the results of every site is the right way as it might mask variation within each site.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer here that there's some confusions about the dataset/structure...

To add some clarification to the error message:
I was having a similar issue and found that the `x` and `y` argument in `testSpatialAutocorrelation()` (and similarly, the `time` argument in `testTemporalAutocorrelation()`) needs to be a vector of *unique* values, and not just the panelized dataframe vector/column of grouping variables.

Example solution using a similar structure from the original question:

```
library(DHARMa)
library(stringr)

SpatData$coords <- paste(SpatData$x,", ",SpatData$y)
coords <- c(unique(SpatData$coords))
x_unique <- c(str_extract(coords, "^.+(?=,)"))
y_unique <- c(str_extract(coords, "(?<=, ).+$"))

sims<-simulateResiduals(SpatLM)
simsrecalc<-recalculateResiduals(sims,group = SpatData$coords)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(simsrecalc, x = x_unique, y = y_unique)
```